# Listview animation when my custom class added/removed/edited

Tags: wpf, class, listview, animation

I have a class called Note, that consists of Title,Content and a Date. And inside listview item template, I have some text blocks and buttons. For now, I can apply animations when edit/remove button clicked, because that buttons' tag are the Grid which I will animate. Since my class is not a framework element, it doesn't have transform and opacity property. How to do so?
Regards,
Talha

Comment: You've really answered yourself- you can't have animations on none- UI objects. So first you'd have to figure out what object you'd want to animate , then you'd need to set a trigger on the appropriate field in xaml which will interact with those UI objects. For example if you add a note via a popup, then you could set a trigger on the 'ok' button to animate such and such object.

Comment: @Oyiwai I can animate it when removed, but not when added because it's added automatically. And the other thing is, where i remove an item, others go correct position immediately(without animation)

Comment: How are the items added? Is there a setter/ add function you could wrap? I'm also a bit hazy about the animation you're looking for- what are you aiming to animate?

Comment: Its added via item source. I will animate items to slide when removed/added/edited. I can animate remove animation because it's called via a button. But I can't animate others to get correct position smoothly with animation, they go to correct position immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `ItemContanerStyle`